# arc lint command fails with error #1

Tags: php, python, pylint, phabricator, arcanist

I've configured [arc lint](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/arcanist_lint/) to use [pylint](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwixo6qxxPLNAhVBOpQKHdjxCasQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pylint.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHL4Nwzaw3j6Nh5W8NLBktlLcgJ_A&sig2=O3ORNIOShCN82kv0dp74Tw) by defining linters in `.arclint` file:

```
{
  "linters": {
    "pylint": {
      "type": "pylint",
      "include": "(\\.py$)"
    }
  }
}
```

After exectuing `arc lint` command on any `*.py` I am getting next exception:

```
[2016-07-12 14:18:10] EXCEPTION: (PhutilAggregateException) Some linters failed:
- CommandException: Command failed with error #1!
  COMMAND
  'pylint' '--reports=no' '--msg-template={line}|{column}|{msg_id}|{symbol}|{msg}' '/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/module/file.py'

  STDOUT
  ************* Module module.file


  STDERR
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/bin/pylint", line 11, in <module>
      sys.exit(run_pylint())
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 23, in run_pylint
      Run(sys.argv[1:])
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 1315, in __init__
      linter.check(args)
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 736, in check
      self._do_check(files_or_modules)
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 867, in _do_check
      self.check_astroid_module(ast_node, walker, rawcheckers, tokencheckers)
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 947, in check_astroid_module
      walker.walk(ast_node)
    File "/Users/aivaneyko/Projects/raw/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylint/utils.py", line 938, in walk
      self.wa... (1,689 more bytes) ... at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistLintEngine.php:274]
arcanist(head=master, ref.master=4d4d16f25985), phutil(head=master, ref.master=32c56dc20b39)
  #0 <#2> ExecFuture::resolvex() called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/linter/ArcanistExternalLinter.php:448]
  #1 <#2> ArcanistExternalLinter::resolveFuture(string, ExecFuture) called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/linter/ArcanistFutureLinter.php:34]
  #2 <#2> ArcanistFutureLinter::didLintPaths(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistLintEngine.php:594]
  #3 <#2> ArcanistLintEngine::executeDidLintOnPaths(ArcanistPyLintLinter, array) called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistLintEngine.php:545]
  #4 <#2> ArcanistLintEngine::executeLintersOnChunk(array, array) called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistLintEngine.php:473]
  #5 <#2> ArcanistLintEngine::executeLinters(array) called at [<arcanist>/src/lint/engine/ArcanistLintEngine.php:216]
  #6 ArcanistLintEngine::run() called at [<arcanist>/src/workflow/ArcanistLintWorkflow.php:334]
  #7 ArcanistLintWorkflow::run() called at [<arcanist>/scripts/arcanist.php:394]
```

My `arc --version` output:

> arcanist 4d4d16f25985f133501f20fdddd183e525f00341 (28 Jun 2016)
>
> libphutil 32c56dc20b39cffd0cfef931f6f4ab9c99f12677 (7 Jul 2016)

My `pylint --version` output:

> pylint 1.5.6,  astroid 1.4.7 Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015,
>   19:19:21)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]

I've faced exception on **PHP 5.5.34**, after upgrading to **PHP 5.6.23** problem still exist. Also I've tried to install other version of arcanist without success - `arcanist 57f6fb59d73994d90cd94143787424ce0fdbf73b (25 Jan 2016)`, `libphutil f43291e99d36045bc459e5133454c0d8fd8768ea (21 Jan 2016)`.

OS: **El Capitan 10.11.5**

Comment: Have your tried to run pylint command in console manually? I have tried arc lint --everything with .arclint file you have provided and it works just fine. I have Pylint version 1.6.1

Comment: @KostyaShkryob Yes, I've tried and it works fine. Also, I've tried pylint 1.6.1 without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the issue was related to `ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8`.

If you have faced the same error on MacOS here's the quick fix (export in bash):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

How to fix :

Please use "test.php" script to reproduce issue (provide path to the file instead of "path-to-file/file"):

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("file", "error_output.txt", "a")
);
$process = proc_open('"pylint" "--reports=no" "--msg-template={line}|{column}|{msg_id}|{symbol}|{msg}"   "path-to-file/file"', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
?>
```

You can check errors in "error_output.txt" file if any exists.

Good luck! :)